Lookup to return status
I have two collections: customers and processed.customers.
customers = {_id, name}

processed.customer: {_id, status, statusDate, processorId}

In processed.customers collection, I save only the customers who are to be processed.
This STATUS can be 1 or 2 or null.
I need to list customers in all situations:
The ones who are not going to be processed (not saved in the other collection)
The non-processed ones yet (their status is null)
Processed with succes (status 1)
Processed with failure (status 2)
For that I tried a lookup. But I can't figure out, how to treat all cases.
I also need to retrieve a list of all cases separately...

const pipeline = [
    { $match: { OfficeId: "b5b5e2d9-c229-4a4d-843e-559f4fee400e" } },
    { $project: { _id: 1, Name: 1 } },
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "processed.customer",
            localField: "_id",
            foreignField: "_id",
            as: "customers"
        }
    },
    { $unwind: "$customers" },
    {
        $project: {
            _id: 1,
            Name: 1,
            Status: "$customers.Status"
        }
    },
    { $match: { Status: 2 } }
];

How can I do that?
Here is the Mongo Playgroung
I tried to lookup and use a switch, and the customers who are in the processed collection, with status null (so waiting for processing), still has no status set. And I need some way to categorize then as well.

Can you provide sample input and expected output documents? Or you can create the Mongo Playground link. Thanks.

Mongo Playground link added

Possibly this demo is what you need. As your second case is to check whether the field is not null, null != undefined/missing, thus this case is fulfilled and ended. You can replace with checking the field is missing and return value as the demo.
